# Oracle 11g IMP functionality

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

Just looking for a little clarification on Oracle 11g imports.

I have a user that DOES have privileges to import & a second user that DOESN'T have privileges to import, I was basically wondering if I can use the user that does have privileges to import into the shemea for  the user the does not.

So if for example:

```
User CANIMP does have privileges
User NOIMP does not have privileges
```

Would this import into the user that does not?

```
imp CANIMP/password123@localhost/ORCL file=my_dumpfile.dmp fromuser=CANIMP touser=NOIMP log=import_details.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FROMUSER` parameter is the schema owner of the exported data.  It seems unlikely that this is the CANIMP user, but perhaps it is.

If in fact the export structures already belong to NOIMP you do not need to specify `TOUSER`.  You only need to specify the `TOUSER` if you are changing the owning schema from the export.  This has nothing to do with the user running the import job.

Incidentally, you're on 11g, so why are you still using IMP ?  The IMP and EXP utilities have been deprecated in favour of DATAPUMP for a long time now.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#i1009203)

Comment: Cheers for that, thought that might be the case just didn't want to dive in there and run an import not being 100%.